# Magento 2: Cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined, 'timepicker' of undefined,'RFC_2822' of undefined

Tags: magento2.2.2, knockoutjs, requirejs, console

Sometimes I'm getting following errors in the console after reloading the page:-

**Cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined**

**Cannot read property 'timepicker' of undefined**

**Cannot read property 'RFC_2822' of undefined**

But sometimes not getting it.actually when this issue did not come in the console then **"Add To Quote"** happening as expected via AJAX  else it's redirecting to 404 page after clicking on this button.

I've also R&D but they were suggesting to add requires JS on custom JS files but there are lots of extensions,files of the custom JS so it's very difficult to debug everywhere so please help me to resolve the issue ASAP.

Please see the attached image for more clarification:-

[image]

Comment: Any update please? it's very urgent.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes things wasn't loaded due to the **improper page loading**.at that time the mode was **"developer"**.after changing the mode to **"production"** issue was resolved.